# How to store the distinct values of a variable in macro variable(s)

Tags: macros, sas

I have a group macro variable, I would like to make its classes in to macro vars. For example:

```
%macro test(group=);
        proc freq data=foll;
        tables &group / out=freqtbl;
    run;
    proc sql;
        create table grp
         (grpid char(4));
        insert into grp
         values('a')
         values('b')
        ;
    quit;
    data freqtbl1;
        merge grp freqtbl;
    run;
    data freqtbl2;
        set freqtbl1;
        call symput(grpid,&group);
    run;    * &a is the first group, &b is the second group;
%mend;
```

This works for 2 classes, but what if it has 3 or more than 3 classes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is a 'class' in this context?

Comment: sex=f/m, status=y/n, etc.

Comment: So you want to create macro variables that contain the unique values of a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro will create a macro variable for each distinct observation in a column for a dataset.

Var=the column you want a set of macro variables for

dataset= the dataset you have the column in

```
%macro var_for_val(dataset=,var=);

    proc sql noprint;

        create table dist_var as
        select distinct &var.
        from &dataset.
        ;
    quit;

    proc sql noprint;

        create table dist_Var2 as
        select monotonic() as id, &var.
        from dist_var
        ;
    quit;

    proc sql noprint;

        select distinct max(id)
        into :max_var
        from dist_var2
        ;
    quit;

    %do i = 1 %to &max_var.;
        %global var_&i.;
        proc sql noprint;

            select distinct &var.
            into :var_&i.
            from dist_var2
            where id = &i.
            ;
        quit;
        %put &&var_&i.;
    %end;
%mend;
%var_for_val(sashelp.class,var=age);

%put &var_1.;
```

Comment: This is great in macro. Thanks! Wish I could marktwo right anwers.

Comment: @Autumn You can, in either or both cases, upvote to show you find it a helpful answer (green up arrow).

Answer (score 5):

```
proc sql;
select distinct age into :cls1-:cls10 
from sashelp.class;
quit;

%put &cls1 &cls2 &cls3 &cls4 &cls5 &cls6 &cls7;
```

You'll still have the issue of knowing when to stop when using this (like in the above, `&cls7` is not resolved).  Set the `-:cls10` or whatever to a high enough value you don't run out of variables.

If you actually would prefer this to be in one variable,

```
select distinct age into :cls separated by ' '
```

would make &cls that has all of the values in it.

You could also do this in the data step - something like:

```
data _null_;
set mydata;
by myvar;
initialvar=65;
if first.myvar then do;
  call symput(byte(initialvar),myvar);
  initialvar+1;
end;
run;
```

This would require you to have it sorted.  You could alternately run a similar set of code off of the `PROC FREQ` result dataset.

Comment: Ya this helps a lot. Thanks!